# Sympy in iPython notebook: printing an entire function

Tags: python, sympy

Currently when printing equations in SymPy it just prints the 'right hand side' of the equation, and does not include the 'left hand side'. E.g.

```
>>> a = b*d
>>> a
b*d
```

Whereas what I would like is:

```
>>> a = b*d
>>> a
a = b*d
```

For which a big part of this is the nice formatting that mathjax gives, and a bit more readability when I'm showing to colleagues who aren't programmers. Is there a way of including the subject of the equation in the output?

N.B. Apologies, my math terminology is not great

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python does not work like that. Variables in Python are just labels.

SymPy is a Python library, not something wrapped around Python, hence it conform to the syntax and semantics of the language. When you write `a=b` you are creating a label `a` that points to the same object (SymPy based or not) as the one to which the label `b` points. For more details check how variables work in Python.

When you create SymPy expressions, you are starting with objects instances of the class `Symbol` and build up. The argument of the `Symbol` constructor is a name mostly used for printing. You can write `a = b = c = Symbol('fancy_name')` and all three labels will point to the same object: the `Symbol('fancy_name')` instance. Check the tutorial in the Sympy docs.

Most of the time you work with SymPy expressions, not functions. As a beginner you do not need to care about functions.

Finally, if for some reason you wish to have equalities or inequalities as expression (most of the time you do not need this) you can create them with

```
>>> relational.Eq(x, y)
x=y
```